# Accessing global set's field gives object that couldn't be converted to string

Tags: globals, craft2

I've been using globals many times but this is my first time encounter with such problem. Let's go from the bottom. I have two global sets with handles `tax` and `company`. The Tax set have only one plain text field `taxRate` which can be accessed like [documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/globals.html#templating) says `{{ tax.taxRate }}`.

The Company set have more plain text fields and one table field.
Odd thing happens when I try to access any plain text field the same way. Example: `{{ company.businessName }}`.

I've tried to see what I get outputted using [dump()](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/dump.html) function of that field and the output is quiet broader than the dump output of `{{ tax.taxRate }}`.

```
{{ dump(tax.taxRate) }}` -> string(2) "20"

{{ dump(company.businessName) }}` -> object(Craft\ElementCriteriaModel)#942 (17) {
["strictAttributes":protected]=&gt;
bool(false)
["_elementType":"Craft\ElementCriteriaModel":private]=&gt;
object(Craft\EntryElementType)#372 (7) {
["componentType":protected]=&gt;
string(11) "ElementType"
["_sourcesByContext":"Craft\BaseElementType":private]=&gt;
NULL
["_classHandle":"Craft\BaseComponentType":private]=&gt;
NULL ... and another dozens lines of it
```

I can access it using `craft.globals.getSetByHandle('company')` but I don't understand why I'm getting **object** returned in the set Company and **string** returned in the set Tax using the same fetch approach?

Answer (score 1):

Well, when I went properly through the output of `{{ dump(company.businessName) }}` I found out right from the start that it is element criteria model of entry type.
That led me to check for the `handle` `company` that could exists twice in system.

I found section with the `handle` `company`. So two identical handles in system were causing my problem. But on the first place, how could Craft let me save the global set with the `handle` that already existed in system even if they are different type of element criteria model and Craft would throw that string conversion error anyway?